# Dialogs not showing correctly using modal=true and appendToBody=true

Tags: forms, jsf, dialog, primefaces, modal-dialog

I read many posts about this issue, but couldn't find a solution.

I have a form at the beginning of my JSF with a commandButton, which should open the dialog. The Dialog has a form inside the Dialog and the property modal and appendToBody. My Page just reloads itself and does not pop up the dialog.

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/site.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

    <ui:define name="content">
         <h:form>
                   <p:commandButton value="Button" id="myButton" onclick="myDialog.show()" />
        </h:form>

        <p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="myDialog"
                        header="Dialog" closable="true" resizable="false" width="600"
                        height="350" modal="true" appendToBody="true" dynamic="true">
                        <h:form>
                           ...
                        </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Can you post `commandButton` code again, it looks like Frankenstein.

Comment: Also post little more code, maybe you have some nested `form` tags...

Comment: ya, sorry. I have edited my commandButton. Well, there are two forms, one outside the commandbutton and one inside the dialog box and the ui:define and ui:composition outside

Answer (score 1):

Change your `commandButton` code to this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Button" type="button" id="myButton" onclick="myDialog.show()"/>
```

This will create an ordinary push button (which calls just JavaScript) and don't do any AJAX or non-AJAX requests to server. Default type of button is `submit`.